# XSLT: check if name of TAG = value

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to make an XSLT that has to check if the `value` is equal to '0' AND if the `@name` is equal to 'Total'.

I think the `name()` only catches 'SUMMA', so how would I catch the 'NIMI = "TOTAL"' ?

This is the XML:

```html
<DOKUMENTTI>
    <LASKU>            
        <SUMMAT>
            <SUMMA NIMI="Mileage allowances" FMT="0,00" TYYPPI="CURRENCY">0</SUMMA>
            <SUMMA NIMI="Expenses" FMT="0,00" TYYPPI="CURRENCY">0</SUMMA>
            <SUMMA NIMI="Total" FMT="0,00" TYYPPI="CURRENCY">0</SUMMA>
            <SEPARATOR/>
            <SUMMA NIMI="Reimbursable" FMT="0,00" TYYPPI="CURRENCY">0</SUMMA>
            <SUMMA NIMI="Taxable" FMT="0,00" TYYPPI="CURRENCY">0</SUMMA>
            <SUMMA NIMI="Advances" FMT="0,00" TYYPPI="CURRENCY">0</SUMMA>
            <SUMMA NIMI="Payable" FMT="0,00" TYYPPI="CURRENCY">0</SUMMA>
        </SUMMAT>
    </LASKU>
</DOKUMENTTI>
```

And this is the XSL check:

```html
<xsl:for-each select="DOKUMENTTI/LASKU/SUMMAT[SUMMA='0']">
  <xsl:if test="name() = 'Total'">
 <message class="3">
   Total can't be 0
 </message>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Name() is total or Nimi is total?

Comment: It has to be "nimi" that should be Total

Comment: What is the value here? <SUMMA NIMI="Total" FMT="5,00" TYYPPI="CURRENCY">0</SUMMA>.?... 5,00 or 0?

Comment: <SUMMA>0</SUMMA>
That is the value of summa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="DOKUMENTTI/LASKU/SUMMAT/SUMMA[@NIMI = 'Total' and . = '0']">
    <message class="3">Total can't be 0</message>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If there's only one `Total` in the whole document, you could also use an `xsl:if` instead of a `for-each`:

```
<xsl:if select="DOKUMENTTI/LASKU/SUMMAT/SUMMA[@NIMI = 'Total'] = '0'">
    <message class="3">Total can't be 0</message>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code help

```
<xsl:for-each select="DOKUMENTTI/LASKU/SUMMAT/SUMMA">
        <xsl:if test="@NIMI = 'Total'">
            <message class="3">Total can't be 0</message>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you want to check 2 conditions. Nimi to be 'Total' and value to be 0.

First loop through all the SUMMA elements.

```
<xsl:for-each select="DOKUMENTTI/LASKU/SUMMAT/SUMMA">
    <xsl:if test="(./@NIMI = 'Total') and (. = '0')">
        <message class="3">Total can't be 0</message>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think this will help to you because i have test it from my side.**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="DOKUMENTTI">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="LASKU">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SUMMAT">
        <xsl:for-each select="./SUMMA">
            <xsl:if test="@NIMI eq 'Total' and normalize-space(.) eq '0'">
                <message class="3">Total can't be 0</message>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```